# SwiftUI VStack alignment guide with other views

Tags: swiftui, vstack, swiftui-alignment-guide

I'm struggling to achieve the following custom alignment in a SwiftUI `VStack`:

[image: Screenshot with correctly aligned subviews]

I've created a custom alignment guide to use in the `Event` view, as follows:

```
extension HorizontalAlignment {
    struct EventLeading: AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in d: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            d[HorizontalAlignment.leading]
        }
    }

    static let eventLeading = HorizontalAlignment(EventLeading.self)
}

struct Event: View {
    
    let date: String
    let event: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
            Text(date)
                .font(.caption)
            Text(event)
                .alignmentGuide(.eventLeading) { d in d[.leading]}
        }
    }
}
```

However, in the same `VStack` are `Divider` views between adjacent `Event`s, and these do not specify the `eventLeading` alignment guide and assume the default (`.leading` in this case):

```
struct VStackAlignedToGuide: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .eventLeading) {
            Event(date: "12 Oct 1568", event: "Born")
            Divider()
            Event(date: "2 Feb 1612", event: "Ate porridge for breakfast")
            Divider()
            Event(date: "1613", event: "Lost a shoe")
        }
    }
}

let test = VStackAlignedToGuide()
    .frame(width: 400)
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(test)
```

This causes the events to shift left and the dividers to shift right:

[image: Screenshot with events shifted left and dividers shifted right]

Is there a way to achieve this simply and cleanly? I've read lots of articles online. This [excellent guide](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/swiftui-layout-system-guide-part-2/#geometry-preferences-and-layout-dependencies) has one possible solution I haven't tried... but my layout requirement seems so simple there must be an easier way!

I thought I might manage it by expanding the frame of the event to the width of the container, and then using the alignment guide within the frame. That way it would not interfere with the alignment of the `VStack`. I've tried lots of combinations without success. This is one:

```
struct Event: View {
    
    let date: String
    let event: String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
            Text(date)
                .font(.caption)
            Text(event)
                .alignmentGuide(.eventLeading) { d in d[.leading]}
        }
        .border(.blue)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,
               alignment:
                Alignment(horizontal: .eventLeading,
                          vertical: .top))
        .border(.black)
    }
}
```

This fails because the `.eventLeading` alignment guide in the individual `Event`s is aligned to the leading edge of the container:

[image: Screenshot of experiment with maxWidth frame and alignment.]

Any help very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### iOS 16 and later

If your deployment target is iOS 16 (released in 2022) or later, use [`Grid`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/grid#):

```
struct EventRow: View {
    let date: String
    let event: String

    var body: some View {
        GridRow {
            Text(date)
                .font(.caption)
                .gridColumnAlignment(.trailing)
            Text(event)
                .gridColumnAlignment(.leading)
        }
    }
}

struct RootView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Grid(alignment: .leadingFirstTextBaseline) {
            EventRow(date: "12 Oct 1568", event: "Born")
            Divider()
            EventRow(date: "2 Feb 1612", event: "Ate porridge for breakfast")
            Divider()
            EventRow(date: "1613", event: "Lost a shoe")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: grid rows aligned as requested]

### Older than iOS 16

There's no elegant way to do this on older versions of iOS. Apple didn't add good layout tools (like `Grid` and [`Layout`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/layout#)) until iOS 16.

One hacky way to do it is to put short, hidden dividers in the `VStack` and collect their `y` positions. Then, overlay the `VStack` with visible dividers at those positions. The visible dividers aren't inside the `VStack` so they aren't subject to its alignment, and they pick up its width automatically. However, you cannot set a visible divider's y position without also setting its x position (lest the divider's x position be set to zero), so you also need to pick up the `VStack`'s x position.

We'll use the `eventLeading` alignment you defined already:

```
extension HorizontalAlignment {
    private enum EventLeading: AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in d: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat { d[.leading] }
    }

    static let eventLeading = HorizontalAlignment(EventLeading.self)
}

struct EventRow: View {
    let date: String
    let event: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
            Text(date)
                .font(.caption)
            Text(event)
                .alignmentGuide(.eventLeading) { d in d[.leading] }
        }
    }
}
```

We also need a structure to collect the y positions of the hidden dividers and the x position of the `VStack`:

```
struct DividerLayoutInfo {
    var x: CGFloat? = nil
    var ys: [CGFloat] = []
}
```

To actually collect the positions, we need to use SwiftUI's [`preference`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/preference(key:value:)) modifier, which means we need a type that conforms to [`PreferenceKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/preferencekey#). We might as well use `DividerLayoutInfo` for that too:

```
extension DividerLayoutInfo: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: Self = .init()

    static func reduce(value: inout Self, nextValue: () -> Self) {
        let nextValue = nextValue()
        value.x = value.x ?? nextValue.x
        value.ys += nextValue.ys
    }
}
```

We'll also need a name for the [`coordinateSpace`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/coordinatespace(name:)) from which we collect positions and in which we lay out the visible dividers:

```
private let geometryName = "myGeometry"
```

We'll overlay the `VStack` with this view to copy the `VStack`'s x center position into a preference:

```
fileprivate struct XReader: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {
            Color.clear.preference(
                key: DividerLayoutInfo.self,
                value: .init(x: $0.frame(in: .named(geometryName)).midX)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

We'll use this view to place each hidden divider into the `VStack` and copy its y center into a preference:

```
fileprivate struct HiddenDivider: View {
    var body: some View {
        Divider()
            .frame(width: 10) // SHORT! So it doesn't mess up the VStack layout.
            .hidden() // Hidden views are still part of layout.
            .overlay {
                GeometryReader {
                    let y = $0.frame(in: .named(geometryName)).midY
                    Color.clear
                        .preference(
                            key: DividerLayoutInfo.self,
                            value: .init(ys: [y])
                        )
                }
            }
    }
}
```

We'll overlay the `VStack` with this view to draw the visible dividers:

```
fileprivate struct VisibleDividers: View {
    let info: DividerLayoutInfo

    var body: some View {
        if let x = info.x {
            ForEach(info.ys, id: \.self) {
                Divider()
                    .position(x: x, y: $0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here's the view that puts it all together, using [`overlayPreferenceValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/overlaypreferencevalue(_:_:)) to access the collected `DividerLayoutInfo`:

```
struct RootView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .eventLeading) {
            EventRow(date: "12 Oct 1568", event: "Born")
            HiddenDivider()
            EventRow(date: "2 Feb 1612", event: "Ate porridge for breakfast")
            HiddenDivider()
            EventRow(date: "1613", event: "Lost a shoe")
        }
        .overlay { XReader() }
        .overlayPreferenceValue(DividerLayoutInfo.self) {
            VisibleDividers(info: $0)
        }
        .coordinateSpace(name: geometryName)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: another grid as requested]

Here's all the code together for your convenience:

```
extension HorizontalAlignment {
    private enum EventLeading: AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in d: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat { d[.leading] }
    }

    static let eventLeading = HorizontalAlignment(EventLeading.self)
}

struct EventRow: View {
    let date: String
    let event: String

    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
            Text(date)
                .font(.caption)
            Text(event)
                .alignmentGuide(.eventLeading) { d in d[.leading]}
        }
    }
}

fileprivate struct DividerLayoutInfo {
    var x: CGFloat? = nil
    var ys: [CGFloat] = []
}

extension DividerLayoutInfo: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: Self = .init()

    static func reduce(value: inout Self, nextValue: () -> Self) {
        let nextValue = nextValue()
        value.x = value.x ?? nextValue.x
        value.ys += nextValue.ys
    }
}

private let geometryName = "myGeometry"

fileprivate struct XReader: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {
            Color.clear.preference(
                key: DividerLayoutInfo.self,
                value: .init(x: $0.frame(in: .named(geometryName)).midX)
            )
        }
    }
}

fileprivate struct HiddenDivider: View {
    var body: some View {
        Divider()
            .frame(width: 10)
            .hidden()
            .overlay {
                GeometryReader {
                    let y = $0.frame(in: .named(geometryName)).midY
                    Color.clear
                        .preference(
                            key: DividerLayoutInfo.self,
                            value: .init(ys: [y])
                        )
                }
            }
    }
}

fileprivate struct VisibleDividers: View {
    let info: DividerLayoutInfo

    var body: some View {
        if let x = info.x {
            ForEach(info.ys, id: \.self) {
                Divider()
                    .position(x: x, y: $0)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RootView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .eventLeading) {
            EventRow(date: "12 Oct 1568", event: "Born")
            HiddenDivider()
            EventRow(date: "2 Feb 1612", event: "Ate porridge for breakfast")
            HiddenDivider()
            EventRow(date: "1613", event: "Lost a shoe")
        }
        .overlay { XReader() }
        .overlayPreferenceValue(DividerLayoutInfo.self) {
            VisibleDividers(info: $0)
        }
        .coordinateSpace(name: geometryName)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for such a prompt and thorough answer. Somehow, after hours of reading articles, I never spotted `Grid`! It has worked for my real world requirement. The pre-iOS 16 suggestion has taught me a few new things, too. Thanks again.